# Using Express to hand off request to ADFS server

Tags: angular, express, authentication, single-page-application, adfs3.0

We're currently running into an issue with authenticating to our on-premise ADFS 3.0 server. We have an Angular app, single page application that has to authenticate with ADFS. We're using an HTTP POST request within the Angular app, but running into CORS issue (naturally as they're not on the same server).

To try and look at it from a different angle, we thought about building a simple Express server, which hosts an API call that we can hit from our Angular/SPA app with a username and password, then the Express server issues the request to ADFS for the authentication. We thought that this would work, as now it's not the browser making the request and get around the CORS issue.

Has anyone got any experience in this and could possibly point me in a useful direction? Are we going down the right path for this?

Thanks,
bengrah.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are reinventing [Angular proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: Hi - we do use this to some extent, but doesn't this proxy.conf file get ditched whenever you run `ng build` ?

Comment: Hi (: it has never happened in my projects (: proxy.conf was more like made once and forgotten by everyone in the team because it just works (:

Comment: Hi again - so you just added the URL to proxy.conf and ran `ng build` and you didn't get any CORS problems?

Comment: sorry, I see the confusion now. it works only for `ng serve`. for the `ng build` it is a different story.

Comment: Any guidance when it comes to `ng build` - that's why i was thinking of the Express server

Comment: after ng build the app would be served on some web server. there are two solutions for CORS here. One - allow origin on ADFS server. Other - make endpoint for ADFS available on the same origin as the hosted Angular app. Here the solution depends on the webserver you use. Nginx has HTTPs Reverse Proxy for such cases. I suppose does not metter which web server it will have some kind of reverse proxy